# Issue with Python while converting excel into dictionary using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary

I tried converting the excel file into dictionary in python using Pandas Library as following

```
import pandas as pd

my_dic = pd.read_excel('zoho.xlsx', index_col=0).to_dict)
```

When I try to retrieve the value from dictionary using key value as

```
print my_dic['Password']
```

It is printing the data with extra arguments

```
{1L: 991253376L} instead of 991253376
```

How to trim those extra arguments.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_dic['Password']` is a dictionary also.  Try `my_dic['Password'][1]`

as an example:

```
my_dic = {"red" : "rot", "green" : "grün", "blue" : "blau", "password":{0:654651054}}

my_dic['password']
Out[27]: {0: 654651054}

my_dic['password'][0]
Out[28]: 6546510
```